# Why HTML form isn't sending any data

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to get data with php, so here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="file" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><br>

    </form>

    <?php
    
        print_r($_POST);

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            print_r($_FILES);
        }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

It always prints an empty array, meaning $_POST is always empty. Could you please help me

Note: it does receive a data if you submit only the file (name is empty)

Comment: NEVER name anything in a form `submit`  if you ever want to do any JavaScript submitting. As for the empty array, perhaps the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) can help

Comment: _"it does receive a data if you submit only the file (name is empty)"_ - what are you talking about here, what "name"?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Show us the output of your code after you have selected a file and submitted the form. What it shows you when you just load the page (before you submit) is irrelevant.